# I have 2 TableViewControllers. By selecting a row in the first TableView, which would display specific data in the second TableView?

Tags: uitableview

I have 2 TableViewControllers.

The first one will contain, for example, all  the supermarkets in my area.

The second one will the contain, for example, all the food that is available for the selected supermarket that I have made in the first tableview.

EXAMPLE (1st TableViewController):

- Market 1
- Market 2
- Market 3
- Market 4
- Market 5

EXAMPLE (2nd TableViewController):
After selecting Market 2:

The following will be displayed in a tableview...
 - Eggs 
 - Bread
 - Milk
 - Noodles

EXAMPLE (2nd TableViewController):
After selecting Market 1:

The following will be displayed in a tableview...
Eggs 
Bread
Chocolates

EXAMPLE (2nd TableViewController):
After selecting Market 3:

The following will be displayed in a tableview...
 - Eggs 
 - Noodles
 - Milk
 - Cereal

Therefore, I would like to know what I should do to allow the different sets of data, to be displayed based on the selected tableviewcell to get it displayed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just in theTableViewController1 `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, set theTableViewController2 tableView data which will used in its TableViewDataSource protocol, then reloadData:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPahth.row == 0){ //Market 1
       theTableViewController2.dataArray = marketdata[0]; //for example, @[Eggs,Bread,Milk,Noodles], depended on you datasource model;
       [theTableViewController2.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know how do I set the property for the .dataArray, and also the .tableView in the TableViewController2?

Also, how do I 'convert' the marketdata[0] to a object like setName?

Thanks!

Comment: dataArray, `@property(strong) NSArray * dataArray;` , like this in TableViewController2.h.  if theTableViewController2 is instance of UITableViewController, tableView is property already.